# Запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Мы – это шесть кирпичных зданий вокруг супермаркета, населенных преимущественно русскими. То есть недавними советскими гражданами. Или, как пишут газеты – эмигрантами третьей волны.

Нужна ли запятая перед тире в последнем предложении, чтобы закрыть вводное?

Если изъять вводное, обособленное запятыми, это останется: Или - эмигрантами третьей волны.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "Или, как пишут газеты, – эмигрантами третьей волны".

В предложении применяется парцелляция - расчленение предложения на самостоятельные части, соответствующие однородным дополнениям.

Вводное предложение с союзом КАК всегда обособляется, постановка запятой и тире независимая.

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, здесь достаточно выделить запятыми вводную конструкцию, а тире совсем не нужно, хотя это и неполное предложение. ("Или, как пишут газеты, эмигрантами третьей волны")